# Disabling SXA rendering dialogs in Experience editor

Tags: sxa, experience-editor

We added SXA module into our newly upgraded Sitecore 10.2 solution. However we found out SXA doesn't work well with our non-SXA solution side by side, especially in the Experience Editor. For example, the new "Select a Rendering" dialog and editor needs to select the right datasource template instead of the datasource created by using the defined template automatically.

We don't want to uninstall SXA, but can we make the experience editor use those default rendering dialogs instead of SXA's?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to override any Sitecore dialog, you can put your own version of it in `sitecore\shell\override` directory.

That's explained here:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/SdnArchive/Scrapbook/Customize%20an%20XML%20Control.html

SXA works in the same way. If you want to disable their version of dialog, delete file:

```
sitecore\shell\Override\Applications\Dialogs\SelectRenderingDatasource\SelectRenderingDatasource.xml
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks Marek.